# I need a way of adding multiple tags with styling to text whilst keep track of its position in a html text area

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, draftjs, slatejs

It's a bit tricky to explain, but I need to produce a React component where the user can select text and apply a "tag" to the text which will make the text bold. I need to record the position of the tags as this data needs to be stored and used in other systems that need to the tag positions.

The complex part is the user can edit the text and apply overlapping tags.

Using Entities in DraftJS I created a solution which supported everything except overlapping tags as in DraftJS multiple entities can't cover the same piece of text.

```js
    private readonly onTagTypeClicked = (tagType: ITagType) => {
        const editorState = this.state.editorState;
        const selection = this.state.selectionEditorState.getSelection();
        if (!selection.isCollapsed()) {
            const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();

            const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
                'TAG',
                'MUTABLE',
                { tag: tagType }
            );

            const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
            const newEditorState = EditorState.set(editorState, { currentContent: contentStateWithEntity });

            this.setState({
                editorState: RichUtils.toggleLink(newEditorState, newEditorState.getSelection(), entityKey)
            });
        }
    }
```

I then tried writing a solution from scratch using a contentEditable div and custom tags, that failed as the html produced malformed html like below

```html
<tag-1 class="tag">This is a <tag-2 class="tag">test</tag-1> of tagging</tag-2>
```

which the browser would try to fix meaning I couldn't keep track of the tags.

I tried hacks using comments to get around the html parsing issue:

```html
<!--tag1--><b>This is a</b><!--tag2--><b>test<!--/tag1--> of tagging</b><!--/tag2-->
```

The comments kept disappearing stopping this approach from working.

I tried the same thing with SlateJS but that proved to glitchy and comments kept disappearing.

```js
public renderMark = (props: any, editor: any, next: any) => {
        switch (props.mark.type) {
            case 'bold':
                return <strong {...props.attributes}> <ReactComment text={'Tag1'} />{props.children} <ReactComment text={'/Tag1'} /> </strong>;
            default:
                return next();
        }
    }
```

Ideally does anyone know of an existing component that can handle what I'm looking for or a robust way of coding a custom solution?

Comment: 1) I would expect that once the user edits the text, that all applying tags would no longer be valid and be discarded, since only the user would know the business logic that made the tag correct for the previous version of the text. My thought is that you're not going to be able to have the script calculate if the previous tag is still valid on the new version of the text. If we would be able to do that, we would have the script add the tags to begin with instead of a user. So that covers the 'users can change text after', the user would have to readd the tags themselves.

Comment: 2) I would write the HTML output as following: `<span data-tag="tag1">This is a </span><span data-tag="tag1 tag2">test</span><span data-tag="tag2"> of tagging</span>`. This is valid HTML and both tags can overlap and can be extracted seperately. A script can then calculate where it should start or end a span and check if it should add spans, or just update an existing span with an extra tag.

Comment: Thank you @Shilly, point 2 is a very good idea, I will have a play and try and come up with a demo.

Comment: So whilst looking up how to work with the text selection API I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLwxj/1/) which with a bit of tweaking appears to do what I need.